# Почему, если написать <?php echo "\u0020" , "<p>qqq</p>";?>, то выведется \u0020<p>qqq</p> в документ?

Tags: php, unicode, ascii

привет.

Почему, если написать  `<?php  echo "\x20" , "<p>qqq</p>";?>`, то выведется в документ `пробел<p>qqq</p>`(пробел - имеется в виду не строка "пробел", а обычный пробел),а если написать `<?php  echo "\u0020" , "<p>qqq</p>";?>`? то выведется `\u0020<p>qqq</p>`? Должно быть одинаково, по идее.

`\u0020` - это `UTF-16` код пробела.

`\x20` - это `ASCII` код пробела.

Какая разница в использовании этих двух вариантов?

Comment: Вот немного из фич php7 - https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.unicode-codepoint-escape-syntax

Comment: @u_mulder как раз наверное ответ в этом и есть, что версия php не 7

Comment: у меня стоит версия пхп 5.3

Comment: Вообще вот тред на стеке http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string# и ответ видимо такой что "PHP does not know these Unicode escape sequences" а с версии 7 таки узнал)

Comment: можно извращаться через json_decode: `json_decode('"\u0020"')` ... либо php7 ставить))

Comment: Кажется, вы путаете ANSI и ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

Я так формально отвечу:

до версии 7 в php нет распознавания последовательностей типа `\u0020`.

Чтобы их правильно распознавать можно воспользоваться решениями из [этого треда на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058394/unicode-character-in-php-string#).

С версии php7 стало попроще, существует [`Unicode codepoint escape syntax`](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.unicode-codepoint-escape-syntax) и писать можно вот так:

```
echo "\u{0020}";
```

Comment: Я бы плюсанул, но я не плюсую xD

Comment: спасибо за ответ. поставил плюс

Answer (score 0):

Потому что ты вводите в первых кавычках строку, потом после запятой идет вторая строка и так получается, что они сливаются вместе. Чтобы добавить пробел, добавьте его в конце первой или в начале второй строки или же так:
echo "blablabla"," ","blablabla"; Во вторых кавычках пробел. Так будет куда проще, на мой взгляд, и не нужны коды кодировок.

Comment: пробел<p>qqq</p> - имеется в виду, что перед <p>qqq</p> выводит пробел

Comment: @Dimon А какая кодировка стоит у Вас в документе?

Comment: кодировка ютф-8 без БОМ. фишка в том, что, если стоит ютф-8, то аски тоже "понимается"